# install mono manual (local) without internet

Tags: mono, embedded, installation, arm

I want to install mono on an embedded system (arm board) it has no ethernet connection, so i need to do a local installation, (i can transfer data / files to the board with sdcard).

Board Data:
32 Kbytes of Internal ROM
64 Kbyte of Internal SRAM

64 Mbytes of SDRAM memory (32-bit bus width)
256 Mbytes of NAND Flash memory (8-bit bus width)

(edit: OS is a busybox 1.12 buildroot)
(edit2: got now a debian grip chroot)

Any ideas how i can get a mono environment to work on the board?

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a cross-compiler or do the build on another more powerful ARM development box, then you make install to a, say, /tmp/arm-install directory and then finally transfer the contents of that dir to the ARM box in the final installation dir.